# Why is (line bundle, appropriate rational section) not a standard kind of divisor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors

In algebraic geometry, there are two standard "kinds" of divisors: Weil divisors and Cartier divisors.  Weil divisors provide better geometric intuition, while Cartier divisors are more general (if not precisely a generalization).  In both of these kinds of divisors, the "key" results seem to be their relation to the Picard group (of isomorphism classes of line bundles).

However, one could also define a "divisor" to be an equivalence class of pairs $(s, \mathcal{L})$, where $s$ is an invertible rational section of $\mathcal{L}$. (By "invertible" I mean that there exists a rational section $s'$ of $\mathcal{L}^{\vee}$ such that $s' s = 1$.) We say $(s, \mathcal{L}) \sim (s', \mathcal{L}')$ if there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{L}'$ taking $s \mapsto s'$.

This definition works well at least for all Noetherian schemes (on which associated points behave nicely), and possibly more generally.  It also seems less confusing than the definition of a Cartier divisor, and the relationship between divisors and line bundles is already embodied in the definition.

So why have I never seen this definition given as a kind of divisor?

[Note: I am aware of what "data" defines a Cartier divisor (the $(U_i, f_i)$, etc.) and how this provides a reasonably natural way to think of Cartier divisors geometrically (the "subscheme" defined locally by the $f_i$). So while I appreciate the thought, please don't waste your time writing a note for the sole purpose of explaining this.]

**Edit:** Since this issue has come up in an answer, I thought I would explain that by "rational section," I mean a (maximally extended) section over an open subset containing all the associated points; or equivalently, a section of $\mathcal{K} \otimes \mathcal{L}$, where $\mathcal{K}$ is the sheaf of total quotient rings of $\mathcal{O}_X$.  (Actually, $\mathcal{K} \otimes \mathcal{L}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{K}$, but not naturally so.)  A rational section can fail to be invertible if it vanishes on one or more associated points.

Comment: You should look in Fulton's book "Intersection Theory".  I believe your definition is (almost) what he calls a pseudo-divisor (Chapter 2).

Comment: EGA IV-4, (21.2.11)?

Comment: I agree with mdeland. Actually a pseudo-divisor is a triple (Z, L, s), where Z is closed, L is a line bundle and s is a section of L outside of Z. Fulton studies their properties and the relation to other definitions in Chapter 2 of his book in intersection theory.

Comment: Since every Cartier divisor is a Weil divisor but not conversely, I would rather say that Weil divisors are a generalization of Cartier divisors...

Comment: I thought the *point* of pseudo-divisors is that the section $s$ can be zero (which allows you to pull-back pseudo-divisors without any problems). So at least the intention of their definition is rather orthogonal to Charles' intention.

Comment: If $K\otimes L$ is isomorphic to $K$, then $L$ injects into $K$ and then $L$ is associated to a Cartier divisor. This however is not true in general. There is an old counterexample by Kleiman (published later in Comm. in Algebra, 2000) and by Schröer (Arkiv der Math. 2000). 

Comment: Okay, it looks to me like this definition is in fact equivalent to the notion of Cartier divisors.  This discussion (esp. Qing Liu's point) has isolated a point that I had not previously realized: namely, that a line bundle is associated to a Cartier divisor iff it has an invertible rational section.

Comment: Note: In fact, EGA IV-4, 21.2.11 is precisely the statement that these divisors are equivalent to Cartier divisors.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to revive an old question, but I think Ravi Vakil uses exactly this notation on page 356 in his online notes:

http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGmay1612public.pdf